# creating virtual file system with apache VFS

Tags: java

For unit tests, I'd like to create an in-memory file system with VFS.

My current code:

```
final String ROOTPATH = "ram://virtual";

        FileSystemManager fsManager = VFS.getManager();
        fsManager.createVirtualFileSystem(ROOTPATH);
        FileObject testFile = fsManager.resolveFile(ROOTPATH + "/test.txt");
        testFile.createFile();

        FileObject testFile2 = fsManager.resolveFile(ROOTPATH + "/test2.txt");
        testFile2.createFile();

        FileObject testFile3 = fsManager.resolveFile(ROOTPATH + "/test3.txt");
        testFile3.createFile();

        FileObject testFile4 = fsManager.resolveFile(ROOTPATH + "/test4.txt");
        testFile4.createFile();

        FileObject folder = fsManager.resolveFile(ROOTPATH);
        FileObject[] files = folder.getChildren();
        for (FileObject file : files) {
            System.out.println(file.getName());
        }
```

My question: Is this the correct way to do it? Examples on this topica are sparse.

I still get the log message:

```
Apr 14, 2015 11:08:17 AM org.apache.commons.vfs2.VfsLog info
INFORMATION: Using "/tmp/vfs_cache" as temporary files store.
```

Can I ignore this, since I am using the ram URI scheme? I guess it's because I didn't configure the DefaultFileSystemManager.

Thanks for help and tips!

EDIT:

Now with the marschall memoryFileSystem:

I copied the example code from their website.

This is my @Test-Method:

```
FileSystem fileSystem = this.rule.getFileSystem();

Path testDirectoryPath  = Paths.get("test");
Files.createDirectories(testDirectoryPath);
Path p = fileSystem.getPath("test");
System.out.println(p.getFileName());
System.out.println(p.getFileSystem());

Path testfile = Paths.get("test/text2.txt");
Path test = Files.createFile(testfile);
Path f = fileSystem.getPath("test/text2.txt");
System.out.println(f.getFileName());
System.out.println(f.getFileSystem());
System.out.println(f.toAbsolutePath());
```

This is the console output:

```
test
MemoryFileSystem[VirtualTestFileSystem]
text2.txt
MemoryFileSystem[VirtualTestFileSystem]
/test/text2.txt
```

Looks alright, however: The files and directories actually get created on my hard drive, in the project folder. I thought, the whole point of this was to avoid exactly that...? Am I doing something wrong or do I just not get it...?

Comment: If you use Java 7+, you should consider using java.nio.file instead; and there does happen to exist a [pretty good in-memory implementation of it](https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! what are the advantages?

Comment: Many; basically, you just use the standard java.nio.file API to manipulate entries in it, just like you would do with files on your local disk.

Comment: Okay, I had a look at it. I cannot for the life of me find out how to add files or directories to the virtual filesystem. The only examples provided just check if a file exists. Could you provide a code snippet?

Comment: See [here](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_java.nio.file_API); it is a page I wrote showing how to use the API. If you are stuck I have [created a room dedicated to this API](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67042/fges-java-nio-file-corner); I lurk in there so if you have questions, feel free to join.

Comment: okay, where do I see how to create a directory and add it to my MemoryFileSystem? I need to pass a directory name to another constructor

Comment: @fge: Java NIO is not related to this question in any way. The question is about how to write a **new** file system (like NTFS, ext4, btrfs), not how to access an *existing* file system.

Comment: Join the room I linked to; a stream of comments won't help matters, and rooms are logged ;)

Comment: @AaronDigulla good, because I also happen to [have an existing library for that](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-base), over which I already implemented `FileSystem`s for [DropBox](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-dropbox) and [box.com](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-box)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I mixed that up with FUSE :-) VFS really seems to be just a high level wrapper.

Comment: Well, the question was about how to use apache commons VFS, but I switched to this marschall memoryfilesystem. I asked a new question.

Comment: I cant post for another 90 minutes... I edited my question

Comment: Have you seen my edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are using Paths.get

```
Path testDirectoryPath  = Paths.get("test");
```

Paths.get always creates paths on the default file system. You should use

```
Path testDirectoryPath  =  fileSystem.getPath("test");
```